# After upgrading from 21.04 to 21.10 my mouse goes invisable on external displays, and also in full screen applications on my main display

Tags: updates, display, mouse

After upgrading I noticed that when playing Rim world my cursor no longer displays in full screen. Ignoring this after a few days I noticed my cursor would also disappear when using external displays. I feel this may be a driver issue, but I don't see why an update would change that.

Comment: Please post at least the basic hardware specifications.

Comment: AMD Radeon r5, 8 gig ram, 1TB hard drive. Laptop. 2 gig base clock.